# I want to take the sum of values in the column when another column has a specific text

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

I want to take the sum of values of column B whenever column A has value x:

```
A    B
x    20
x    12
y    12
x    54
y    97
x    12
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(if($A$1:$A="x",$B$1:$B)))
```